# Why does the combination of find + insert work faster than the single insert statements

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

Why does the combination of `find` + `insert` work faster than the single `insert` statements?

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_set>

int main()
{
    {
        auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

        auto elements = 100000000;
        std::unordered_set<int> s;
        s.reserve(elements);
        for (int i = 0; i < elements; ++i)
        {
            auto it = s.find(i % 2);
            if (it == s.end())
            {
                s.insert(i % 2);
            }
        }

        auto t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

        std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(t2 - t1).count() << std::endl;
    }

    {
        auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

        auto elements = 100000000;
        std::unordered_set<int> s;
        s.reserve(elements);
        for (int i = 0; i < elements; ++i)
        {
            s.insert(i % 2);
        }

        auto t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

        std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(t2 - t1).count() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

This code gives me the following results in MSVC-14.0 (Release configuration ofc):

```
716
1005
```

Comment: How many elements in each?

Comment: @Tas I've provided the fully working minimal example

Comment: [No repro](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6ad13af005d334a2), your measuring method seems to be wrong.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ Maybe it does not reproduce in GCC but it **does** reproduce in MSVC-14.0. This is what I've said in the OP post

Comment: @FrozenHeart Run each of these methods a several 1000 times and gather the average execution time results. A single pass measured in one run isn't significant (no matter if MSVC or gcc).

Comment: Perhaps I don't understand the code, so I'm only trying to be clear. The last example inserts 100000000 elements, whereas the first example doesn't insert as many?

Comment: @Tas It doesn't actually insert those elements, it tries to insert them

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ I ran that code 100 times for each of the cases and it gave me the following results -- 88392 and 116971

Comment: @FrozenHeart _"it tries to insert them"_ [Think twice what makes the difference then](http://i0.wp.com/hotnerdgirl.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/triple-facepalm.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Since the elements you're adding most of the time are already in the set, `insert` has more work to do thatn `find` as it needs to construct a pair with the iterator pointing to the existing element in the set and a boolean to indicate that the element is already there.  `find` only has to return the iterator.  You can look at the library code to see this.

A more accurate title and question almost gives you the answer.  Since you're only inserting two elements, then checking for around 100,000,000 more, a better title would end with "when the elements are already in the set".  A better question is "why does `find` work faster than `insert`?".